Specify output directory and binary name to zig build-exe
I struggle to find any equivalent of C compiler's cc <srcs> -o <path/and/binary/name> in documentation of zig build-exe. Only thing that I found is option --name, but It cannot  specify path, only name of unit.
Is there any way to do so in command, or using build.zig file is the only way?

-femit-bin=path/to/output_file
Similar options are available for emitting other things

That is it! Thank you
